# Show an image in Opencv on button click in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I have been working on Tkinter GUI and new to it. Now I want to display an image using Opencv, on button click in a seperate window, so first I fetch  the image path using askopenfilename() and then passing that value to cv2.imread()
Below is the code.

```
openpath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
if openpath:
   image = cv2.imread(openpath)
   cv2.imshow("slot", image)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyWindow("slot")
```

Image shows up in a new window but when I try to close it, Tkinter application also closes. I need to perform some task on the image and then close it on key press not affecting my Tkinter application. Can it be accomplished using thread. if yes then how can i do it? Please guide
Thank you

Comment: Can you paste your whole code into a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/). I need to see the definitions of your windows.

Comment: I will attach the snapshots of GUI and the paste the code of the file I am using as module in my main.py

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused  I have done a work around by opening the image into new window of tkinter and placed it in Canvas. Will paste the code below. Comments would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is a work around. It opens the image in canvas TKinter.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.create_frame()

def create_frame(self):
    global image

    cv_frame = Frame(self.parent)
    cv_frame.pack()
    imagepath = load_image()
    image = Image.open(imagepath)
    image = image.resize((1072, 650), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas = Canvas(cv_frame, width=tkpi.width(), height=tkpi.height())
    canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=tkpi)
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.pressdown)                      ##binding for left button when its pressed
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.pressup)                 ##binding for left button when its released
    canvas.bind("<Double-Button-3>", self.reset)                   ##binding for right button double click will reset the drawn lines 
    canvas.image = tkpi
    canvas.pack()

    frame = Frame(cv_frame)
    frame.pack()
    crop = Button(frame, text="Crop", width=6, command=self.crop)
    crop.pack(side=LEFT)
    save = Button(frame, text="Save", width=6, command=self.save)
    save.pack(side=LEFT)

def pressdown(self, event):                       ##event handler for left button when button is pressed
    coords.append(event.x)
    coords.append(event.y)
    allpoints.append((event.x, event.y))

def pressup(self, event):                       ##event handler for left button when released
    cord.append(event.x)
    cord.append(event.y)
    allpoints.append((event.x, event.y))
    event.widget.create_line(coords[0], coords[1], cord[0], cord[1], fill="green", width=4, dash=(4, 4), tag="line")
```